# Python converting byte to unicode string

Tags: python, django

How can I display this text:

```
text = seccure.encrypt(b'message\n', b'coR5M|FpR*Vn')
```

text is displayed as `\x00\x146\x98` in terminal.

I tried:

```
arr = bytearray("'%s '"%(txt, ),"ascii")
testmsg1 = arr.decode("ascii")
```

But the display is 'b'\x0\x0fx\xf4' ' with quotes included. it is different from text.

Comment: Where you want to display it? Console? HTML?

Comment: What does this have to do with django?